# Injecting current into the feedback node of an LDO/DCDC, bad idea?

Tags: voltage-regulator, feedback

I'm trying to control an LDO/DC-DC converter externally (using a DAC for example). I was thinking of injecting current into the feedback pin (see the schematic below for illustration), is that a bad idea ? Anything I should be extra careful with ?

I aim to drop the output voltage past the regulator's voltage reference, is there any issue with doing that ?

*The regulator's load, capacitors and voltage source were omitted from the schematic*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZgnea.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

EDIT:
The ADJ pin might have caused a misunderstanding.

I was referring to regulators which use a constant voltage reference going into the error amp, such as TPS74701:
[image: TPS74701 Block Diagram]

Comment: Your first diagram shows a 3-terminal regulator. With only 3 terminals there can't be a separate ground reference. The device you then link to is not a 3-terminal regulator.

Comment: -1 for changing the question after an answer has already been posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I aim to drop the output voltage past the regulator's voltage reference, is there any issue with doing that ?

It should work... with caveats.

Your scheme holds the FB pin at its nominal value, so the error amp inside the regulator won't notice the change.

However, the TPS74701 you show uses a NMOS, so the circuit that drives it will only work inside a specific voltage range. I don't know if this range extends down to an output voltage close to 0V. Maybe... maybe not.

(If you look at ThePhoton's answer, this would correspond to the output voltage range of the opamp.)

I would tend to think that it will work, since the regulator has a soft start. Looking at the first datasheet page, which shows a turn-on Vout curve, we can see that the output voltage makes a jump from 0 to about 0.25V, then it rises smoothly. However there is no way to know if this "jump" is due to the MOSFET driver only being able to drive the output down to 0.25V and not below (which would be bad for your application) or due to the error amp's feedback input not being able to process voltages close to 0V (which you don't care about), or due to some other cause.

A more usual LDO with a PMOS pass device would have no such issue. Or just use ThePhoton's opamp-based reg (but mind the compensation vs output caps).

Answer (score 1):

Edit: The question originally posted proposed using a 3-terminal regulator. It was later edited to propose using a different type of regulator. I will leave this answer posted for future readers who might be considering something similar with a 3-terminal regulator.

Here's a diagram of the internals of the LM317 regulator:

[image]

Note: LM317 is a linear regulator, but it is not a *low drop-out* linear regulator. An LDO may have a somewhat more complex circuit, but this will mostly still apply.

The key things to notice are:

- current must be allowed to flow out of the ADJ pin for the circuit to work.
- The circuit maintains the output voltage at 1.25 V above the ADJ pin.
- As typically used, the circuit has no connection to a ground node, so it is relatively indifferent to what happens at the ground node in your circuit.

You can use this to buffer a DAC by simply connecting the DAC output to the ADJ pin. In your circuit diagram, this would mean removing R2 and reducing R5 to 0 ohms. The DAC must be capable of sinking current. Then the regulator output will equal the DAC output voltage plus the regulator's reference voltage.

> I aim to drop the output voltage past the regulator's voltage reference, is there any issue with doing that ?

You can do this by pulling the ADJ pin below ground.

If you try to do it by injecting current in to the ADJ pin it will more likely just make the reference circuit not work correctly.

A more common way to buffer a DAC output is to simply use an op-amp buffer, possibly with a further external transistor buffer if high current is needed. This eliminates the offset by Vref and associated errors.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fu1FZi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(Note: This circuit can only source, not sink, output current)

Comment: I was actually thinking of regulators with constant voltage reference, i'll update the questions.

Comment: @Mike, when you post a question you need to remember that all we know about what's in your mind is what you include in the question. If you show a schematic with a 3-terminal regulator, we're going to think that a 3-terminal regulator is what you plan to use.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I still appreciate your answer and have learned from it.